# Is there an upside-down version of the symbol for $\pi$?

Tags: graphics, symbols, greek

I have been looking at the [Comprehensive list of Latex symbols](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), but can not seem to find an upside-down letter $\pi$. Is there a package that I need to add so that a command like $\copi$ or $\invpi$ or should one create such a symbol manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create upside-down versions of `\pi` with the help of the `\rotatebox` and `\reflectbox` macros of the `graphicx` package. Two possibilities are shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % provides "\rotatebox" and "\reflectbox" macros
\newcommand\rotpi{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\pi$}}
\newcommand\copi{\reflectbox{\rotpi}}
\begin{document} 
$\pi \rotpi \pi \copi $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, this is not part of the original question, but perhaps you might know if there is a way to obtain the mirror image of the upside down $\pi$? I'm just wondering if it might look more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @sqtrat `\newcommand\rotreflpi{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\reflectbox{$\pi$}}}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you, I'm not very familiar with all these graphic packages like TikZ, graphicx and so forth. Perhaps I should start looking at them...

Comment: @sqtrat - I've updated my answer to show a second possibility, viz., `\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\pi$}}`.

Comment: @sqtrat It is just mirroring after rotating rather than rotating after mirroring. Only the order of operations is different, as far as I can tell.